# Windbg, how to check memory segment permission?

Tags: debugging, memory, permissions, windbg

For example output stack as non-executable, some heap is executable/non-executable..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[!address](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff561519(v=vs.85).aspx) or [!vprot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff565611(v=vs.85).aspx) (UM) extentions display virtual memory protection information.

```
0:000> !address 0038f750
Usage:                  Stack
Allocation Base:        00290000
Base Address:           0038d000
End Address:            00390000
Region Size:            00003000
Type:                   00020000    MEM_PRIVATE
State:                  00001000    MEM_COMMIT
Protect:                00000004    PAGE_READWRITE
More info:              ~0k

0:000> !vprot 0038f750
BaseAddress:       0038f000
AllocationBase:    00290000
AllocationProtect: 00000004  PAGE_READWRITE
RegionSize:        00001000
State:             00001000  MEM_COMMIT
Protect:           00000004  PAGE_READWRITE
Type:              00020000  MEM_PRIVATE
```

Comment: +1. for execution permission you need to look at Protect field, which displays [memory protection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366786(v=vs.85).aspx)